# Program to print from line 30 to 50 only

Tags: c, operators

I am trying to write a program which read the file and print lines from line#30 to line#50 but not able to achieve it.

main() {

```
FILE *fp;
char ch;

int nol = 0;
fp = fopen ("test.txt","r");

while (1){
    ch = fgetc(fp);

    if (ch == '\n')
        nol++;


    if (nol > 30 || nol < 50){
        printf ("value of NOL is %d\n", nol);
    }


    if (ch == EOF)
        break;


}
fclose (fp);
printf ("\nNumber of line in file: %d\n", nol);
```

I tried with if nol >=30 and nol <=50 condition and tried to print but that is not working. Any input will be of great help.

Comment: `char ch` & `if (ch == EOF)` is bad! Make `int ch`.

Comment: Eddy_Em, it is a line so should be reading it as char right not the int?

Comment: Usually `EOF == -1`, so in your case char with value of 255 will be like EOF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the logic part.

Generally we think of line numbers as beginning at 1 instead of 0.  So initialise `nol` to 1.

If you want to display lines 30 to 50, then you need to include them in the test.  Use `>=` instead of `>` (same for `<`).

And of course you need to use `&&` instead of `||`, otherwise your condition is always true.

If you want to actually display the lines, you need something like this:

```
if( nol >= 30 && nol <= 50 ) putc(ch);
if (ch == '\n') nol++;
```

Note the order of the statements.

But really, you should look at using `fgets` if you want to display the lines, instead of reading one character at a time.

Comment: Thanks all looks like it is working. I am using printf ("%c",ch) so it is printing only one character so if I want to print whole lines from line# 30 to 50 then what should I use?

Comment: This information is in my answer.  Did you not read it?

Comment: Paddy, Yes I tried it but it give me an error (using MAC OS) Number of <pre> line in file: 433
Devangs-MacBook-Air:cprog jimdev$ gcc fileread.c 
fileread.c: In function ‘main’:
fileread.c:27: error: too few arguments to function ‘putc’
Devangs-MacBook-Air:cprog jimdev$ <pre>

Comment: Oops I meant `putch(ch)`.  Or you could use `putc(ch, stdio);`

Comment: Paddy, I used putc (ch, stdout); and its working now. Thanks everyone for help.

Answer (score 4):

The "and" operator is `&&`, not `||`

...

```
if (ch == '\n')
{    nol++;
     if (nol >= 30 && nol =< 50) 
         printf ("value of NOL is %d\n", nol);
}
```

If you want to print the line itself and not only the number, you will need to collect the char or something else to print it when find an `'\n'`.

Comment: @devnp said `I tried with if nol >=30 and nol <=50 condition`